# IF-ELSE issue in Select Statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, if-statement

I have following query in SQL Server which I am trying to convert to Oracle 11g.

```
IF '[Param.1]' = 'S' OR '[Param.1]' = 'T' THEN
select * from ULQUEUE
END IF
```

But when I write the same query in Oracle, it gives error stating Invalid SQL Statement. So how do I incorporate IF-ELSE in Select Statement in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

You are converting a T-SQL statement.  The equivalent in Oracle is an anonymous PL/SQL block.

However, PL/SQL is a bit more demanding than T-SQL.  It requires selecting rows into variables.  If the query will return more than one row we need to define a collection variable or use a cursor.

Depending on your requirements you may enbd up with something like this:

```
begin
    if ( &&param1 = 'S' or &&param1 = 'T' ) then
        for lrec in ( select * from ulqueue ) loop
           do_something;
        end loop;
    end if;
end;
/
```

I agree this looks like more work than T-SQL, but PL/SQL is a proper programming language with a lot more functionality.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm).

Comment: Thanks.But how do I display the result of query: select * from ulqueue .. My requrement is, when I pass Param.1 as 'S' or 'T', the query just should display all the fields of ULQUEUE table.

Comment: How are you running this?  What's the client?

Comment: I'm running it through SAP MII Query Editor.